# Copy certain text from one div into another div

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I want to be able to copy certain text from one div into another div.

The text is generated from a Wordpress Plugin, and it generates 2 different divs, with the following classes 1 called .voting inactive and the second one called .voting.

The text generated is rating based is it will look something like: Rating 4.5/5, i ONLY want to take the 4.5 or whatever vote is generated and copy that into a div to display the result nicely.

Any help would be great.

Comment: hello Paul, mind changing your display name, and is it wordpress plugin problem??

Answer (score 2):

I'm with @Starx on this one. But just to be a little more clear:

```
<div>
    Rating
    <span id="average">4.5</span>/
    <span id="highest_possible">5</span>
</div>

<div id="target">
    <!-- This could be any element -->
</div>
```

Then the JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#target").html($("#average").html());
});
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get it working- thanks for all your answers :-)

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
#target-rating{font-size:30px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
/*$(document).ready(function() { 
       //var arrayOne = $('.voted').html().split('/');
       var arrayOne = $('div[class*="voted"]').html().split('/');
       var arrayTwo = arrayOne[0].split(' '); // arrayTwo[1] contains ie: 4.4
       $('#target-rating').html(arrayTwo[1]);
});*/
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// This works for 2 divs
$(function() {
      var rating = $('div.inactive,div.voted inactive').text().replace(/^.*: ([\d\.]+).*$/, '$1'); // Extract the rating
      $('#target-rating').text(rating); // And copy
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="target-rating"></div>

<!-- Example divs -->
<div class="inactive" id="gdsr_mur_text_796_1">Rating: 4.4/<strong>5</strong> (5 votes cast)</div>
<div class="voted inactive" id="gdsr_mur_text_796_1">Rating: 5.0/<strong>5</strong> (5 votes cast)</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

An example

HTML

```
<div id="this">Sometext</div>
<div id="that"></div>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#that").html($("#this").html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var vote = $(".voting").text().split("/")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="hello">Copy It</a>
<a class="goodbye"></a>


(function($) {
    $('.hello').click(function() {

      $(this).clone().appendTo( ".goodbye" );
    });
})(jQuery);
```