# Getting text of a paragraph in jquery

Tags: jquery, text

I am new to JQ, forgive me for this simple question, but I can't figure it out. I need to simply copy the text of a paragraph (it has to be a

element) into an other paragraph when the button is clicked.

But the I get the [object HTMLParagraphElement] message every time insted of the actual text.

Thank you for your help!

```
let tex1=$("#text1").text();
$("#getText").click(function(){
$("#text2").text(text1);
});

<button type="button" id="getText">Get text</button>
<p id="text1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit</p>
<p id="text2"></p>
```

Comment: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818649/send-copy-text-within-one-html-element-to-another-using-jquery) looks like it might solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third line should be:

```
$("#text2").text(tex1);
```

due to the apparent misspelling of "text" in the first line. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j7cyt8ks/) to prove it works.

Comment: I think you meant to use `$(...)` instead of `#(...)`